# Regex on sentences

Tags: php, regex

I built a regex to match sentences in a PHP script, it works great though, it misses the first sentence. Here is the PHP including the regex.

```
preg_match_all('([A-Z][^\.!?]*[\.!?]\s)', '$data', $arr, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

The string used for testing.

> Persoonsgegevens van 84.000 Bol.com-klanten waren toegankelijk via een
>   lek in de site van een externe partij waar Bol.com mee samenwerkte.
>   Het ging om een kwetsbaarheid voor sql-injectie. De gegevens zijn
>   volgens Bol.com niet misbruikt.
>
> De webwinkel heeft de getroffen klanten uit zichzelf geïnformeerd,
>   blijkt onder meer uit een topic op GoT. Het gaat om 84.000 klanten die
>   meededen aan de 'kennismakingsactie' Warm Welkom.
>
> De klantgegevens stonden in een database van een externe partij waar
>   Bol.com mee samenwerkte voor de actie, zegt Bol.com-directeur Daniel
>   Ropers tegenover Tweakers.net. Van de klanten konden naam, geslacht,
>   e-mailadres en geboortedatum worden achterhaald; betaalgegevens waren
>   niet toegankelijk.
>
> "We hebben gisteravond klanten geïnformeerd die eind vorig jaar hebben
>   meegedaan aan de marketingactie", zegt Ropers. "Via het bureau dat de
>   actie heeft verzorgd waren gedurende een bepaalde periode gegevens
>   toegankelijk." Het lek zou in ieder geval vorig jaar zomer al in de
>   software hebben gezeten. Sinds februari waren de gegevens versleuteld.
>   Volgens Webwereld gaat het om een lek in de tool amfphp.
>
> Bol.com ondernam actie nadat het bedrijf werd getipt. Ropers: "Buiten
>   de tipgever is er niemand bij de data geweest; er is niets uitgelekt.
>   We zijn de tipgever zeer dankbaar." Hij benadrukt dat Bol.com zelf
>   niet is gehackt, maar zegt ook dat het bedrijf desondanks zijn
>   verantwoordelijkheid wil nemen. "Voor alle bedrijven waar we mee
>   samenwerken hebben we security-checklists. Daar moeten we dus een stap
>   verder in gaan."
>   Source: [Tweakers.net](http://tweakers.net/nieuws/82873/gegevens-deel-bol-punt-com-klanten-waren-toegankelijk-via-sql-injectie.html)

Comment: Is `'$data'` the string you want to match?

Comment: Nope, I added the test string.

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen: It's generally hard to decide what is a sentence and what is not. In poorly formatted text, we need more information to decide whether "shdfsdf.com sdfsj" is one or two sentences. The most you can do is tweak the regex so that it works for your input - but not necessarily with every input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this regex to match sentence:

```
'.*?([\.!?]+|$)'
```

Add a bit more tweaks here and there gives a better looking output for the test input (test input only - no guarantee for general text):

```
/[\S].*?(?:[\.!?]+["]?(?=\s)|$)/
```

Comment: It works with \s added. '.*?([\.!?]\s+|$)' Otherwise it would match every instance of .

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen: That's my intention for sentence like `Ah... Um... I don't know`

Comment: i see, my issue is more with things like `10.000`

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen: Check my edit for a tad bit better regex. No guarantee for badly formatted text, though.